# How to initiate a single calculation from batched document onWrite triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a subcollection with documents. If any of them are added or removed, I need to trigger a calculation to derive an overall count (amongst other things) and store that in the parent document.

In order to listen for the document changes, I have a firestore onWrite background function. From this function, I would like to trigger the calculation via pubsub. However, it will happen that the system updates many subcollection documents at once. If I delete 100 documents, I do not want the calculation to be triggered 100 times. That would be a real waste of resources.

So I'm wondering, is there already some sort of mechanism in place that would batch these triggers or the pubsub topic publishing, or do I need to do something specific to make this happen?

If there are other ways to better solve this problem I'm open to suggestions of course. I could possibly even introduce a Redis store if that helps.

Comment: What you're describing is known as debouncing. I'm not sure if PubSub supports that natively, but knowing the term might help you find that out. :)

Comment: The problem is that debouncing requires that you have shared state between instances, which Cloud Functions works hard to minimize. So if you want to implement it on that side, you'll need to track that state in your database, which will hurt scalability (which is precisely why Cloud Functions doesn't offer many primitives for it).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Shared state is why I mentioned Redis. In a different project I applied Redis (aka Memorystore) to have a shared cache for all of my cloud functions. There I used it for memoization and not for debouncing, so I'll have to look up how to best implement that.

I don't think it's wise to abuse Firestore for these kind of things. It's clearly not made for anything with frequent low latency write operations.

I think there's still work to be done by the Firebase team to make it easier to integrate something like Memorystore, but I've already made a feature request for it

Comment: Thanks for filing that feature request. But until such a integration exists, you'll need to work with what is there. For frequent small writes you're better off using Realtime Database over Firestore. But you'll need to check for yourself if that fits your model.

Comment: Good point! Maybe the realtime db could be an easy temporary workaround since it doesn't require anything to set up. Ever since I've grown to appreciate many things about Firestore I'd prefer to stay away from it, but I could make an exception :)